# What does "bleibt der Abwasch schon mal liegen" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Der Haushalt ist für ihn aber nicht so wichtig. Wenn er keine Zeit hat, bleibt der Abwasch **schon mal** liegen.

Source: "Direkt", LektorKlett, a story about a boy who lives alone

Comment: what exactly are you having trouble with? Abwasch = dirty dishes, liegen = to lie, bleiben = to stay, remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He doesn't take care of the washing-up immediately, leaving the dirty dishes (in the sink, we may presume) for now, putting it off.

Comment: And what "schon mal" means? Is it used for emphasis?

Comment: @user9065 Simplified: "schon mal" => "sometimes" (in that context)

Comment: Can I ask for the non-simplified answer? On dict.cc (http://www.dict.cc/?s=schon+mal) I've found it can mean "ever".

Comment: It means, literally, "on occasion", i.e. it happens.

Comment: @user9065 "ever" is another translation in another context. "Have you ever been in London -> Bist du schon mal in London gewesen"

Answer (score 8):

> Das kann **schon [ein]mal** vorkommen.

is a colloquial way of expressing that something may happen once in a while. It also implies a certain carelessness and/or fatalistic attitude in respect to the event and its consequences. How frequent exactly this "occasional" event is expected to happen depends on context - from the wording in your example, I'd guess you shouldn't be overly surprised to find dirty dishes in/around the sink more often than not.

Your confusion with the translation as **"ever"** you found in the dictionary comes from a different use case:

> Hast du das **schon [ein]mal** erlebt.

is a way of asking if you have **ever**(literally "once") experienced this before.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, in Germany, we often use "bleibt der Abwasch schon mal liegen." not only for dishes. Sometimes, "bleibt der Abwasch schon mal liegen." is a general sentence to tell, that we dont have time to keep the house clean.